# Excel - Query for CSV missing columns

Tags: vba, excel, csv, powerquery

So I'm using Office 2016's new Query feature to get data from various CSV API endpoints. I managed to get it to work with Yahoo Finance's but I can't seem to get Morningstar's to work. When I visit this link in my browser, I download a full CSV with all the proper data:

Link: http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?t=MSFT&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=10&number=3

However, when I use the query feature, it only loads the first row. I'm guessing it's because only the first column in the first row in the CSV has data, causing it to ignore the rest of the columns. Does anyone know how to ignore that first row and begin importing the CSV from the second?

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?t=MSFT&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=10&number=3"),[Delimiter=",",Encoding=1252])
in
    Source
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: In Csv.Document, it looks like there's an extraValues parameter; maybe that might help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra values parameter can retrieve your extra rows (using ExtraValues.List), but the shape of the table will be difficult to work with.

Here's one way to get the values:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary((Web.Contents("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?t=MSFT&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=10&number=3")),null,null,1252)}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Source,1),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Top Rows","Column1",Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv),{"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4", "Column1.5", "Column1.6", "Column1.7"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", type text}, {"Column1.4", type text}, {"Column1.5", type text}, {"Column1.6", type text}, {"Column1.7", type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type")
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
```

This query treats the CSV file as a text document of lines. It removes the first line, which is some header statement that causes the parser to think that the CSV file has only one column. It then splits the lines into columns based on comma placement and then makes the first row the column names.

Answer (score 0):

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260840.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396:

```
let

Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Projects\Examples\SalesForceContacts.txt"),
    [Delimiter=",",Encoding=1252]),
    #"First Row as Header" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source),
    ...
```

But if the header row is corrupt, this may not work.

Comment: While this promotes the header, I'm still missing all of the other columns! I think it's because the promotion occurs after the data is read, so it doesn't affect what data I'm able to get.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly specify number of columns, it is determined using the first row.
As the first row of your example contains values in the first column only, resulting table also contains only one.

This code returns 7 columns:

```
let
    Source = Web.Contents("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?t=MSFT&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=10&number=3"),
    Csv = Csv.Document(Source,[Delimiter=",", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
in
    Csv
```